# Generic Comparison in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I am currently reading up on Generic Comparison's in TypeScript. I get it that types are removed when transpiling from TypeScript to JavaScript so you can't compare two generic types.

So this is a 3-part question.
Question 1:  Can someone explain what `extends Array` does here?
Question 2: I know when I console.log(c3), I get `[ '1', '2', '500', '600' ]` So when I call `concatenate(l1, l4)`, because `l1` and `l4` share the same ID and type, const `oneList` is created and then returned?
Question 3: What is T1 doing?  Is it essentially the ID being used for `list1` and `list2`?

```
class IdentificatedGeneric<S> extends Array<S> {
    public id: string; // Enhancement of Array class
    public constructor(id: string) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }
}
function concatenate<S, T1 extends IdentificatedGeneric<S>>(list1: T1, list2: T1): T1 {
    if (list1.id === list2.id) { // Comparison to ensure from the same id, possible because both extends IdentificatedGeneric
        const oneList = [...list1, ...list2] as T1;
        return oneList;
    }
    throw Error("Must be the same id");
}

const l1 = new IdentificatedGeneric<string>("l1");
const l2 = new IdentificatedGeneric<string>("l2");
const l3 = new IdentificatedGeneric<number>("l1");
const l4 = new IdentificatedGeneric<string>("l1");

l1.push("1", "2");
l2.push("100", "200");
l3.push(5, 6);
l4.push("500", "600");

const c3 = concatenate(l1, l4);
console.log(c3);
```

Comment: Hmm, where did you find this code? The signature for `concatenate()` is bad; it falsely claims to return some subtype of `IdentificatedGeneric` when in reality it is returning a plain old array without an `id` property.  The compiler will let you write `c3.id.toUpperCase()` without warning even though it blows up at runtime.  Anyway this means that Q2 and Q3 have "I don't know what's going on here but it's not right" as the answer.

Comment: @jcalz This was on a website https://www.educative.io/courses/learn-typescript-complete-course/qAqYnNW8l6y.  This is a course I am taking,

Comment: heh, uh oh.  That's unfortunate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: The `extends` in `class Foo extends Bar` is part of JavaScript (well, [ECMAScript 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) and above) and not only part of TypeScript's static type system.  Therefore it does not get erased.  If the target JavaScript version is ES2015 or later, the emitted JavaScript code will contain `class Foo extends Bar` directly.  If it is something lower, like ES5, it will be transpiled to code which works the same (ish), but will still be included.  Both `Foo` and `Bar` constructors will exist in the emitted code.

Anyway, `class Foo extends Bar` is called [subclassing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Sub_classing_with_extends), and it produces a class constructor `Foo` whose instances will inherit behavior from the superclass `Bar`. Also, `new Foo() instanceof Bar` will be `true` (all `Foo` instances are also `Bar` instances), but `new Bar() instanceof Foo()` will be `false` (not all `Bar` instances are also `Foo` instances).

When the superclass is `Array` as in `class ABC<T> extends Array<T> {}`, it means that you are [extending a built-in class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends#Using_extends_with_built-in_objects).  Every instance of your subclass should also be an instanceof `Array`.

---

Now the rest of your question is a bit confusing because the code for `concatenate()`  is... well, it's not good. I will answer what the type signature *says* it does, and note how it differs from what the implementation *actually* does:

```
declare function concatenate<S, T1 extends IdentificatedGeneric<S>>(
  list1: T1, list2: T1
): T1;
```

This signature says that `concatenate()` takes two arguments, both of which are some *subtype* `T1` of `IdentificatedGeneric<S>` for *some* type `S`.  (Since `S` is not mentioned directly in either the `list1` or `list2` parameter type, the compiler has no clue how to infer it and will likely infer `unknown` for it.  So let's ignore `S` for now). And the return value of `concatenate()` will be the same `T1` type as each of its inputs.  So if the inputs are both, for example, `IdentificatedGeneric<string>`, then the return type will also be `IdentificatedGeneric<string>`. Meaning it has an `id` property of type `string`.

Note from the implementation that this is not true:

```
  if (list1.id === list2.id) { 
    const oneList = [...list1, ...list2] as T1; // 
    return oneList;
  }
  throw Error("Must be the same id");
```

That `oneList` is absolutely *not* an `IdentificatedGeneric` of any sort.  It's just a regular `Array` because it was made as an array literal.  Remember, while all `IdentificatedGeneric` instances are `instanceof Array`, *not* all `Array` instances are `instanceof IdentificatedGeneric`.

And this is why the implementation is using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and saying `as T1`.  If you leave that off, the compiler will rightfully complains:

```
const oneList = [...list1, ...list2];
return oneList; // error!
// Type 'T1[number][]' is not assignable to type 'T1'.
```

the compiler is saying "wait, you said you're returning a `T1`, but you actually just took elements from a `T1` and put them into a plain array.  That's not the same".  Whoever implemented this used a type assertion `as T1` to just tell the compiler "trust me, it's the same".  But this is a lie!  Oh well.

---

So, the rest of your questions:

Q2: checking that `id` is the same only really happens at runtime, while checking that the type parameter in `IdentificatedGeneric<T>` is the same only really happens at compile time.  They are unrelated.

So when you call `concatenate(l1, l4)`, this does not give a compiler error because both are `string` arrays, but this has nothing to do with what happens at runtime.  And it does not give a runtime error because both `id`s are the same, but this has nothing to do with the code compiling without warning.

If you call `concatenate(l1, l3)`, you will get a compiler warning, but the emitted JavaScript will not throw an error and `oneList` will still be created if you run the code.  On the other hand, if you call `concatenate(l1,l2)`, the compiler will be happy with it, but there will be an error at runtime because the `id` field is not the same.

---

Q3: `T1` is the specific identical subtype of `IdentificatedGeneric` that is passed to `concatenate()`.  If you subclass `IdentificatedGeneric` you can get `T1` to be inferred as that subclass.  This happens if you pass two instances of the subclass into `concatenate()`... and the signature says the output will be of the same subclass type:

```
class Sub1 extends IdentificatedGeneric<string> {
  prop1 = "hello"
}
concatenate(new Sub1("l1"), new Sub1("l1")).prop1.toUpperCase();
// here T1 is inferred to be Sub1
```

As I said before though, the implementation does no such thing.

---

As an aside, here's one way I might improve `concatenate()`:

```
function concatenate2<S>(
  list1: IdentificatedGeneric<S>, 
  list2: IdentificatedGeneric<S>
): IdentificatedGeneric<S> {
  if (list1.id === list2.id) {
    const concatList = new IdentificatedGeneric<S>(list1.id);
    concatList.push(...list1, ...list2);
    return concatList;
  }
  throw Error("Must be the same id");
}
```

See how the implementation is actually returning a real `IdentificatedGeneric`?  It creates a new one and fills it with elements.

Also, I am no longer claiming that `concatenate()` can return *any possible* subtype of `IdentificatedGeneric`.  Instead, if you pass in two `IdentificatedGeneric<S>` for the same type `S`, it will return another `IdentificatedGeneric<S>`.  This signature is only generic in `S` and you do not have to worry about dragging possible subtypes around.  for example, the following code is now fine:

```
const c2 = concatenate2(new Sub1("l1"), new Sub1("l2")); // IdentificatedGeneric<string>
```

Here `c2` is no longer considered to be a `Sub1` by the compiler, but just an `IdentificatedGeneric<string>`... which it is.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSAmBTAdgFwJYDN3DKx8A4iogE44A8AygHzSIAe+y8MAgqaWAJ7V0DeAKGjQADgFcARiBzR08AFzQIqcsgDmAbmgB6HdACiyABZhkwRAFsUqaAHtM0Dl27RQkCMLFSZwN3eQVUnFgVDtSAAp5JSD0DQBKaCEREQhxUTII+M0vEVRjdAgAOnloAF45eByRAF9BOsxxcwwA-3M8FA7qABpoABUARnomFFY4JDQsHA6iEnJgPhoImRUBpUHeldQAJnWB+L2kryxoZcLUAZL4crKKre2rxP5dfQBhO0tRMHIIVrD6QLiUiIaCYUgfaD5EEQMDWSq9UR2KDoaQgySIXDiCBouz5YbMMYIGxTXD4WbIMg4XJtFT2CkAGXO5WgAG0iuytgNeuyivcALrVFLA1BA5B0xCMlTaPT9AYs5DiSzo0h8ll8uQwZC46BgWVeOp5YzggDuhk44QiACIALJY2zoyHGaGwkHyS3ZeqCQTAAK0kBDCoU01EybYUkEYgU+YUWIaJaW-3unI+wK2EDbZlB8bEsMzSOUhax9Tx9NJ72+tMAZkziGDEwwubJ+ejCqVZBLAzLKb9ABYa3Wc9Mm3NKEWO2XBP6ihIIMYrZ3epbtmX09OsXPLQMAAxby2L7Y7leVteziIAVl6ADYPSAeyeN2fD4vL4ePeXU25qxUU+HkB1lly0C3h63Z2CAiC8nY6gRMAlZvu4UDQFQUhDIwBIwCGDZDhGI6FqocTFkcIiiOCogBtAlpOiAIB2Janoyj+HR-vgERZshkgDFaibxL0bEoVxnbxPE06kZcYQAKqiBkpCvJAiBZDkXqNM06CtIxzAdNsfBnKsSiYSSea4XwmznLs2ahth5IFnwBzmVh4ZWdGtBEXIjg6RcVw3HcpmPC5IjdrY6mSrYga1nZBnDlGlC0O5lzyB6KRtKSwX3hEPKctyHKmQlQqICKpBikF5yCgajomma4KRDadrQA6ULKC6lRlnU760sAGbfgEv6aaxYXsZxCaCbxfX8Qmy5CdK+j6Y2OFRXhajFoIQA)